# Can a snakemake input rule be defined with different paths/wildcards

Tags: shell, bioinformatics, snakemake, qsub

I want to know if one can define a input rule that has dependencies on different wildcards.

To elaborate, I am running this Snakemake pipeline on different fastq files using qsub which submits each job to a different node:

1. fastqc on original fastq - no downstream dependency on other jobs
2. adapter/quality trimming to generate trimmed fastq
3. fastqc_after on trimmed fastq (output from step 2) and no downstream dependency
4. star-rsem pipeline on trimmed fastq (output from step 2 above)
5. rsem and tximport (output from step 4)
6. Run multiqc

MultiQC - https://multiqc.info/ - runs on the results folder which has results from fastqc, star, rsem, etc. However, because each job runs on a different node, sometimes Step 3 (fastqc and/or fastqc_after) is still running on the nodes while other steps finish running (Steps 2, 4 and 5) OR vice-versa.

Currently,  I can create a MultiQc rule which waits on results from Steps 2, 4, 5 because they are linked to each other by input/output rules.

I have attached my pipeline as png to this post. Any suggestions would help.

What I need: I want to create a "collating" step where I want MultiQC to wait till all steps (from 1 to 5) finish. In other words, using my attached png as guide, I want to define multiple input rules for MultiQC that also wait on results from fastqc

Thanks in advance.

[image: My current Snakemake pipeline as png]
**Note**: Based on comments I received from '[colin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251276/colin)' and '[bli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1878788/bli)' after my original post,  I have shared the code for the different rules here.

Step 1 - fastqc

```
rule fastqc:
    input:  "raw_fastq/{sample}.fastq"
    output: "results/fastqc/{sample}_fastqc.zip"
    log: "results/logs/fq_before/{sample}.fastqc.log"
    params: ...
    shell: ...
```

Step 2 - bbduk

```
rule bbduk:
    input: R1 = "raw_fastq/{sample}.fastq"
    output: R1 = "results/bbduk/{sample}_trimmed.fastq",
    params: ...
    log: "results/logs/bbduk/{sample}.bbduk.log"
    priority:95
    shell: ....
```

Step 3 - fastqc_after

```
rule fastqc_after:
    input:  "results/bbduk/{sample}_trimmed.fastq"
    output: "results/bbduk/{sample}_trimmed_fastqc.zip"
    log: "results/logs/fq_after/{sample}_trimmed.fastqc.log"
    priority: 70
    params: ...
    shell: ...
```

Step 4 - star_align

```
rule star_align:
    input: R1 = "results/bbduk/{sample}_trimmed.fastq"
    output:
        out_1 = "results/bam/{sample}_Aligned.toTranscriptome.out.bam",
        out_2 = "results/bam/{sample}_ReadsPerGene.out.tab"
    params: ...
    log: "results/logs/star/{sample}.star.log"
    priority:90
    shell: ...
```

Step 5 - rsem_norm

```
rule rsem_norm:
    input:
        bam = "results/bam/{sample}_Aligned.toTranscriptome.out.bam"
    output:
        genes = "results/quant/{sample}.genes.results"
    params: ...
    threads = 16
    priority:85
    shell: ...
```

Step 6 - rsem_model

```
rule rsem_model:
    input: "results/quant/{sample}.genes.results"
    output: "results/quant/{sample}_diagnostic.pdf"
    params: ...      
    shell: ...
```

Step 7 - tximport_rsem

```
rule tximport_rsem:
        input: expand("results/quant/{sample}_diagnostic.pdf",sample=samples)
        output: "results/rsem_tximport/RSEM_GeneLevel_Summarization.csv"
        shell: ...
```

Step 8 - multiqc

```
rule multiqc:
    input: expand("results/quant/{sample}.genes.results",sample=samples)
    output: "results/multiqc/project_QS_STAR_RSEM_trial.html"
    log: "results/log/multiqc"
    shell: ...
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. You say steps 1 and 3 have no downstream dependency, but you don't want MultiQC to run until they complete? That sounds like a dependency. If those rules create output that is required for MultiQC, then those output files should be specified as input files for the MultiQC rule. If not, there shouldn't be a reason that those steps need to complete before the MultiQC step is executed.

Comment: You should probably show at least the `input` section of your current `multiqc` rule and the `output` section of your `fastqc` rule.

Comment: @Colin The dag/png lists the current dependencies. Please let me know if I need to explain further. As of now, I tell 'rule multiqc' to wait on output of 'rsem_norm' (which outputs data to results/quant/{sample}). I would like multiqc to also wait for outputs from 'fastqc' and 'fastqc_after' which output to 'results/fastqc' and 'results/bbduk' respectively. Here is where I need help - and hence the original question in the first place.

As you see here, the important directory is the 'results' directory and its subfolders - MultiQC will work on this top level directory.

Comment: @bli I have added different rules to my question. MultiQC needs directory as input - I give it the 'results' directory in my shell command. All the steps have their log files in different folders/subfolders under 'results' and MultiQC has the ability to descend into all of them and provide a report. What's happening here is this: as each job is being submitted to different nodes by qsub, the MultiQC step finishes running when the previous steps (the way I coded) finish.. And that leads me to my original question: how can I give 3 different folder paths as input for the MultiQC rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want rule `multiqc` to happen only after `fastqc` completed, you can add the output of `fastqc` to the input of `multiqc`:

```
rule multiqc:
    input:
        expand("results/quant/{sample}.genes.results",sample=samples),
        expand("results/fastqc/{sample}_fastqc.zip", sample=samples)
    output: "results/multiqc/project_QS_STAR_RSEM_trial.html"
    log: "results/log/multiqc"
    shell: ...
```

Or, if you need to be able to refer to the output of `rsem_norm` in your `shell` section:

```
rule multiqc:
    input:
        rsem_out = expand("results/quant/{sample}.genes.results",sample=samples),
        fastqc_out = expand("results/fastqc/{sample}_fastqc.zip", sample=samples)
    output: "results/multiqc/project_QS_STAR_RSEM_trial.html"
    log: "results/log/multiqc"
    shell: "... {input.rsem_out} ..."
```

In one of your comments, you wrote:

> MultiQC needs directory as input - I give it the 'results' directory in my shell command.

If I understand correctly, this means that `results/quant/{sample}.genes.results` are directories, and not plain files. If this is the case, you should make sure no downstream rule writes files inside those directories. Otherwise, the directories will be considered as having been updated after the output of `multiqc`, and `multiqc` will be re-run every time you run the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks @bli your solution worked.  I had initially tried it  'without the expand' and it was not working.

I initially had my ```multiqc``` input as: ```'results/quant/{sample}.genes.results'```, ```'results/fastqc/{sample}_fastqc.zip'```   -- however, the use of expand the way you have suggested has helped solve the problem.

 ```results/quant/{sample}.genes.results``` are actual files - so If I had sampleA, sampleB, sampleC as my starting material, I would get results/quant/sampleA.genes.results, results/quant/sampleB.genes.results, results/quant/sampleC.genes.results as output